# Is passing NULL for COM interface arguments valid?

Tags: com

If I have a COM interface method expecting BSTR and SAFEARRAY parameters, but these are optional, what is the correct way to implement this? Can I pass NULL or do I need to pass empty strings and zero-length arrays? Or would I be better passing VARIANTs which can be VT_EMPTY *or* VT_BSTR / VT_ARRAY?

e.g.

```
Login([in]BSTR Name, [in]BSTR Password /*optional*/);
SendEmail([in]SAFEARRAY *To, [in]SAFEARRAY *Cc /*optional*/);
```

In these examples, should `Password` be passed as NULL or ""? And should `Cc` be passed as NULL, or do I need to create a 0-length SAFEARRAY, or pass a VARIANT of type VT_EMPTY... which are valid/sensible options?

Comment: Erm, "implement this"?   Sure sounds like you are fretting over calling it.  Be precise please.  And do post the declaration of the method so we don't have to guess.

Comment: I'm merely asking if you can pass NULL, or must pass "empty objects" instead. This affects the COM implementation knowing what to check for, for optional parameters.

Comment: `NULL` is valid value for `BSTR`, regardless whether it is treated as optional argument or not. I don't think it is the case with safe arrays and there should be a valid pointer there. You can pass `NULL` for arrays and other pointers, and it would work if implementation receives the call directly, without marshaling. Marshaler however is likely to fail on unexpected `NULL`s. `defaultvalue` and `optional` are applicable to `VARIANT`s only.

Answer (score 2):

Well, those sort of arguments really aren't quite right--the MIDL compiler should throw a warning or even an error if you try to make anything other than a VARIANT to be "optional".

The correct way is to define default values ("defaultvalue").  For BSTRs you want to make the default value to be L"" and not 0 (NULL).  If you make the default value for BSTRs to be 0, you will run into problems down the road--I think in some .NET interop.

For the SAFEARRAY it should be safe to make the "defaultvalue" to be NULL.

Of course, this advice is from the point of designing how the interface **ought to be.**  You may be in the situation where someone has already designed and implemented the interface.  In that case, you're at the mercy of their implementation.  For the BSTR arguments, I would try passing in empty strings (L"") and for the SAFEARRAY I would try passing in NULL.

If you are going to define it as "optional", make it a variant.  And in that case, the correct argument is VT_EMPTY.